# passing a hash to a route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In the preview action in my controller, I have

```
@models = Model.all
```

In the view, Im trying to loop through all the models, draw out their associated images, and use those to link_to their own profiles.

```
<% @models.each do |m| %>
<div> <%= link_to(image_tag (m.avatar.url(:thumb)), model_path())%> </div>
<% end %>
```

I need to pass in the id of each model to the route. Using m.id doesn't work because the route is expecting a hash.

Not entirely sure how to do this. Other posts on SO refer to unsaved instances and such, which aren't really relevant to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your view code from this:

```
<% @models.each do |m| %>
<div> <%= link_to(image_tag (m.avatar.url(:thumb)), model_path())%> </div>
<% end %>
```

To:

```
<% @models.each do |m| %>
<div> <%= link_to(image_tag(m.avatar.url(:thumb)), model_path(m))%> </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual the error might be in a completely different place - your brackets.

`model_path` can accept both list of attributes and a hash. Most likely you think it is expecting a hash due to the error message (which you should include in the question). In fact however, you are passing the path to the `image_tag`, not to the `link_to`:

```
link_to(image_tag (m.avatar.url(:thumb)), model_path())
```

is parsed as

```
link_to( image_tag(m.avatar.url(:thumb), model_path()) )
```

While:

```
link_to(image_tag (m.avatar.url(:thumb)), model_path())
```

is parsed as

```
link_to( image_tag(m.avatar.url(:thumb)), model_path() )
```

This space between a method name and a bracket is a silent killer. It is a `image_tag` which is expecting a hash in a second argument. :)

That being said - it will still not work, but you should get a different problem now.

Comment: There is no difference between the original and your suggestion

Comment: There's a massive difference, spaces in ruby (sometimes) matter. The whole answer is about what difference that space makes. Also, why would your resurect 8 years old question?

Comment: @MorganS42 - Count brackets, carefully

Comment: The parsed line is obviously different. But the unparsed lines are identical. Anyway, I stumbled upon your meta question about this answer, after it was shown as "active" because of some grammar edits. Only realised how old the question was after commenting.

Comment: AH, you got me there! Yeah, they're the same :) I'll leave it as is as a historic site :P